# Embeded serializers in DRF for mongo and django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am trying to create a non model embeded serializer in Django Rest Framework. I'm stuck here. Need you help. Thanks in advance.

```
class IPNetwork(serializers.ListSerializer):
    network_netmask = serializers.IPAddressField(required=False)
    network_gateway = serializers.IPAddressField(required=False)
    network_mac = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    network_dns = serializers.ListField(required=False)
    network_ip = serializers.IPAddressField(required=False)

class RouterInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    router_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    router_ip_networks = IPNetwork(many=True)
    router_devices = serializers.ListField(required=False)
```

I'm using DRF serializers to authenticate API data but storing it in mongoDB. So i can't use Model Serializer. 
So I wanted to know if there is any way to write nested serializers without using the Model serializers. Nested serializers mentioned [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

My sample input data will be in this format

```
{
  "name": "Test Router",
  "ip_networks":[
    {
      "ip": "192.168.1.1",
      "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
      "gateway": "192.168.1.1",
      "mac": "EA:8C:0C:1F:BC:DC",
      "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
    }
  ],
  "router_devices": ["List of clients connected"]
}
```

On this data input, I want to validate the ip data also in the serializer and then call the save function.

I want something similar to embedded document [mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#embedded-documents)

Comment: I'm sorry you're stucked but I have no idea what help you are looking for. Maybe starting by explaining what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that you have `IPNetwork(many=True)` and set `IPNetwork` as `ListSerializer`.

One should know that this is redondant as many=True creates a `ListSerializer` behind the scene. Also note that `ListSerializer` are intended to work with a child serializer which is different from your implementation.

Therefore, you should simply make `IPNetwork` inherit from `serializers.Serializer` and you should be good to go.

Non model serializers works - mostly - the same as `ModelSerializers` except that they return python dictionaries unless the create/update are overridden. Note that in your case with nested serializers, those two methods should be overridden anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Inherited from serializers.Serializer. But not implemented the create/update functions. Using serializer for data validation only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So this is how i did and it works great.

```
class IPNetwork(serializers.Serializer):
  network_netmask = serializers.IPAddressField(required=True)
  network_gateway = serializers.IPAddressField(required=True)
  network_mac = serializers.CharField(required=True)
  network_dns = serializers.ListField(required=True)
  network_ip = serializers.IPAddressField(required=True)

class RouterInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  router_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
  router_ip_networks = serializers.ListField(required=True)
  router_devices = serializers.ListField(required=False)

  def validate_router_ip_networks(self, value):
    if not IPNetwork(data=value, many=True).is_valid():
      raise serializers.ValidationError("Router IP network data is invalid")
    return value
```

Let me know if any issues with this code or anyone has any queries.